# My attempts at writing a NESTED CASE/WHEN statement isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck with on a CASE/WHEN statement
What I need to do is check if a value is found in `HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME` - If yes then use `HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME` in date diffrence  calculations otherwise use current date.

Here is what I've written but it doesn't appear to work. Any suggestions on this approach or another method

Thanks
Steve

```
            -- Calculate L
            CASE

                WHEN HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME is NULL
                THEN
                      CASE
                          WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) < 1 THEN 0 
                          When ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) BETWEEN 4 and 6 THEN 4 
                          WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) BETWEEN 7 and 13 THEN 5 
                          WHEN  ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0)>= 14 THEN 6
                          ELSE ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0)
                ELSE 
                      CASE
                          WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) < 1 THEN 0 
                          WHEN ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) BETWEEN 4 and 6 THEN 4 
                          WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) BETWEEN 7 and 13 THEN 5 
                          WHEN  ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0)>= 14 THEN 6
                          ELSE ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0)
                END 
                      END AS L,
```

Comment: How does it not work?  Sample data and desired resuls are helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you need `DATEDIFF(dd, coalesce(HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME, GETDATE()), GETDATE())`

Comment: You need an END on your first inner CASE.   Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing an END -

```
-- Calculate L
CASE
    WHEN HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME is NULL
    THEN
          CASE
              WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) < 1 THEN 0 
              When ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) BETWEEN 4 and 6 THEN 4 
              WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) BETWEEN 7 and 13 THEN 5 
              WHEN  ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0)>= 14 THEN 6
              ELSE ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0)
          END -- Added this
    ELSE 
          CASE
              WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) < 1 THEN 0 
              WHEN ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) BETWEEN 4 and 6 THEN 4 
              WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) BETWEEN 7 and 13 THEN 5 
              WHEN  ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0)>= 14 THEN 6
              ELSE ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,PAT_ENC.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0)
          END -- Fixed indentation
END AS L, -- Fixed indentation
```

Because this works (which just replaces the columns I can't see with variables I declare):

```
DECLARE @HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME datetime
DECLARE @HOSP_ADMSN_TIME datetime
SET @HOSP_ADMSN_TIME = GETDATE() - 4

SELECT CASE
WHEN @HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME is NULL
    THEN
          CASE
              WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) < 1 THEN 0 
              When ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) BETWEEN 4 and 6 THEN 4 
              WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0) BETWEEN 7 and 13 THEN 5 
              WHEN  ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0)>= 14 THEN 6
              ELSE ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,GETDATE()),0)
          END
    ELSE 
          CASE
              WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,@HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) < 1 THEN 0 
              WHEN ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,@HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) BETWEEN 4 and 6 THEN 4 
              WHEN   ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,@HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0) BETWEEN 7 and 13 THEN 5 
              WHEN  ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,@HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0)>= 14 THEN 6
              ELSE ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd,@HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,@HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME),0)
    END 
END AS L
```

Comment: Thanks everyone - I didn't see the missing END. This solved my problem